# Case statements evaluate to strings

Tags: bash, functional-programming, notation, case-statement

I've caught the functional programming bug, so naturally nothing is good enough for me anymore. ;)

So, in bash one could write:

```
case $status in
  "foo") status="bar" ;;
  "baz") status="buh" ;;
   *) status=$status ;;
esac
```

but I'm afraid of typos, so I'd **prefer** to write:

```
status=case $status in
  "foo") "bar" ;;
  "baz") "buh" ;;
  *) $status ;;
esac
```

The second form is invalid since the case evaluates to the exit code of the last executed command, which is not at all what I'm looking for.

Are there easy hacks to achieving what I **am** looking for?

Comment: are you just wanting to write a function?

Comment: If you are afraid of typos, use [`set -u`](https://sipb.mit.edu/doc/safe-shell/) at the beginning of your program.

Answer (score 25):

If you're sure status will only be one line, you could do something like this with sed:

```
status=$(echo "$status" | sed -e 's:^foo$:bar:' -e 's:^baz$:buh:')
```

You may also be able to get something to work with bash's built-in substitution. This *almost* works (I don't know of any way to get exact matching only):

```
status=${status/foo/bar}
status=${status/baz/buh}
```

If your goal is just to be more "functional" (and not to make your code more typo-proof), you could do this:

```
status=$(
  case "$status" in
    ("foo") echo "bar" ;;
    ("baz") echo "buh" ;;
    (*) echo "$status" ;;
  esac)
```

Though honestly, bash is probably one of the worst languages to try and be functional in. It was really designed with a more imperative mindset, as illustrated by the fact that you can't easily compose expressions. See in the second code snippet how I had to break it into two separate statements? If bash were designed to be functional you'd be able to write something like this instead:

```
status=${{status/baz/buh}/foo/bar}
```

But that does **not** work.

I'd suggest only using bash for simpler scripts, and for more complicated stuff use something like Python or Ruby. They'll let you write more functional code without having to constantly wrestle with the language.

Comment: zsh will let you do nested parameter expansions like your last example.

Comment: @mbac32768 as far as I can tell I did answer your question, three times in fact. If you disagree maybe you need to reword your question, or you could at least explain why these solutions don't work for you. Getting snarky when someone puts effort in trying to help you out is kind of lame.

Comment: I read his answer to your question as "no, and here's why and some other options".  Great answer.

Comment: @mbac32768 Didn't you ask how to write that switch statement in a functional way? And didn't I show you three alternatives? As for pointing out that you shouldn't try to program functionally in bash, it's pretty it's very common for answers on Stack Overflow to take a step back and point out when the question indicates a bigger problem. If finding out that you're taking a walk down the garden path hurts your feelings then maybe you shouldn't be asking questions on Stack Overflow, or you can learn to deal with constructive criticism.

Comment: @mbac32768 How does the `status=$(...echo...)` thing not answer your question? You were looking for a hack to do this, here you are. Quite frankly, you are being a dick here (or were being 8 years ago).

Answer (score 5):

```
status="baz"
status=$(case $status in
  "foo") echo "bar" ;;
  "baz") echo "buh" ;;
  *) echo $status ;;
esac)
echo "status: $status"
```

output

```
$ ./shell.sh
status: buh
```

Comment: That's the third snippet I posted, but with syntax errors. (The close parens inside `$(...)` confuse bash, so you need to use the optional open paren on each case.)

Comment: what do you mean confuse bash?

Comment: ok, i guess you are using bash <4.0 . In 4.0, i think this is fixed.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still using 3.x (I'm using an LTS version of Ubuntu). It's interesting that 4 can parse that.

Answer (score -1):

Bash 4 has associative arrays:

```
# setup
unset vals i
indices=(foo baz)
val=(bar buh)
declare -A vals             # associative
for index in ${indices[@]}
do
    vals[$index]=${val[i++]}
done

$ # demos
$ status="foo"
$ status=${vals:-$status}
$ echo $status
bar
$ status="not found"
$ status=${vals:-$status}
$ echo $status
not found
```

Comment: Is that really how you are supposed to initialise associative arrays in bash4?

Comment: @Charles: It's one way that's expedient for this demo. I could have done `for index in foo baz` for example, instead of using an array. Or done a direct bulk assignment or read from a file. What is it in particular that you're asking about?